# Norm in $L^2$ goes to zero for function away from zero

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $M>0$. Define $f_M(x)=f(x)$ for $|x|\leq M$ and $f_M(x)=0$ for $|x|>M$. Show that $\|f_M-f\|_2\rightarrow 0$ as $M\rightarrow \infty$.

Well, we have $$\|f_M-f\|_2^2=\int_{|x|>M}|f|^2dx$$

Since $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, we know that $$\int_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f|^2dx<\infty$$ But why does this imply that $$\int_{|x|>M}|f|^2dx\rightarrow 0 \text{ as } M\rightarrow\infty?$$

Comment: Dominated convergence theorem is one possible way to see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because

$$\int_\mathbb{R} |f|^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n\ ,$$

where $A_n = \int_{\{n< |x|\leq  n+1\}} |f|^2$. Then $\int_{|x|>M} |f|^2 = \sum_{n=M}^\infty A_n \to 0$.